# how to add button click event in android studio

Tags: java, android, button, view, android-studio

So I have done some research, and after defining you button as an object by the code

```
private Button buttonname;
buttonname = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonnameinandroid) ;
```

here is my problem

```
buttonname.setOnClickListener(this); //as I understand it, the "**this**" denotes the current `view(focus)` in the android program
```

then your `OnClick()` event...

Problem:

When I type in the "this", it says:

```
setOnClickListener (Android.View.view.OnClickListener) in View cannot be applied to (com.helloandroidstudio.MainActivity)
```

I have no idea why?

here is the code from the .java file

```
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Button btnClick;
    private EditText Name, Date;
    private TextView msg, NameOut, DateOut;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button) ;
        btnClick.setOnClickListener(this);
        Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textenter) ;
        Date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText) ;
        msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtviewOut) ;
        NameOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtoutName) ;
        DateOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtOutDate) ;
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if (v == btnClick)
        {
            if (Name.equals("") == false && Date.equals("") == false)
            {
                NameOut = Name;
                DateOut = Date;
                msg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {
                msg.setText("Please complete both fields");
                msg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
        return;

    }
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

> SetOnClickListener (Android.View.view.OnClickListener) in View cannot
>   be applied to (com.helloandroidstudio.MainActivity)

This means in other words (due to your current scenario) that your MainActivity need to implement **OnClickListener**:

```
public class Main extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
   // do your stuff
}
```

This:

```
buttonname.setOnClickListener(this);
```

means that you want to assign listener for your Button *"on this instance"* `->` this instance represents **OnClickListener** and for this reason your class have to implement that interface.

It's similar with anonymous listener class (that you can also use):

```
buttonname.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {

   }
});
```

Answer (score 13):

```
Button button= (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    // click handling code
   }
});
```

Comment: This answer is definitely not wrong, but in general, answers are more helpful (and more likely to be upvoted) if they contain some description of _why_ they work, instead of just _what_ to do to fix the problem. Welcome to the community!

Answer (score 10):

```
package com.mani.smsdetect;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    //Declaration Button
    Button btnClickMe;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Intialization Button

        btnClickMe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClickMe);

        btnClickMe.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
        //Here MainActivity.this is a Current Class Reference (context)
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        //Your Logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
package com.mani.helloworldapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    //Declaration
    TextView tvName;
    Button btnShow;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Empty Window
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Load XML File
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Intilization
        tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        btnShow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShow);

        btnShow.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        String name = tvName.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give any description to your answer?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply set onClickListener on a Button or anything using Lambda Expression which looks like

```
private Button buttonname;
buttonname = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonnameinandroid);

buttonname.setOnClickListener(v ->
    {
       //Your Listener Code Here
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

When you define an `OnClickListener` (or any listener) this way

```
btnClick.setOnClickListener(this);
```

you need to `implement` the `OnClickListener` in your `Activity`.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener{
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
```

Whenever you use (this) on click events, your main activity has to implement ocClickListener. Android Studio does it for you, press alt+enter on the 'this' word.

Answer (score 2):

Start your OnClickListener, but when you get to the first set up parenthesis, type new, then View, and press enter. Should look like this when you're done:

```
Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
//your stuff here.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> //as I understand it, the "this" denotes the current view(focus) in the android program

No, "this" will only work if your `MainActivity` referenced by `this` implements the `View.OnClickListener`, which is the parameter type for the `setOnClickListener()` method. It means that you should implement `View.OnClickListener` in `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new MyClass());

    }

    public class MyClass implements View.OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in Activity java class you would need a method first to find the view of the button as :

```
btnSum =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
```

after this set on click listener

```
btnSum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

and override  onClick method for your functionality .I have found a fully working example here : http://javainhouse.blogspot.in/2016/01/button-example-android-studio.html

Answer (score 0):

Your `Activity` must implement `View.OnClickListener`, like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends 
Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
// YOUR CODE
}
```

And inside `MainActivity` override the method `onClick()`, like this:

```
@override
public void onClick (View view){
//here YOUR Action response to Click Button 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do nothing but, just type `new View.OnClickListener()` in your `btnClick.setOnClickListener()`. I mean you have to type 
`btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener` the bracket will remain open, just hit enter then a method will be created like this,

```
btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
```

It's just mean that you are creating a new view of OnClickListener and passing a view as it's a parameter. Now you can do whatever u were supposed to do, in that onClick(View v) method.

Answer (score 0):

**At first, Find the View**

```
 Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //Actions that will be done when clicked...
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Different ways to handle button event

```
Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(context, "Button 1", 
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

[[Check this article for more details about button event handlers]](http://kodecenter.com/article?id=e1f43037-946b-4e71-9887-7354df4749dd)

Answer (score -2):

```
public class EditProfile extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button searchBtn;
    EditText userName_editText;
    EditText password_editText;
    EditText dob_editText;
    RadioGroup genderRadioGroup;
    RadioButton genderRadioBtn;
    Button editBtn;
    Button deleteBtn;
    Intent intent;
    DBHandler dbHandler;

    public static final String USERID_EDITPROFILE = "userID";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile);

        searchBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.editprof_searchbtn);
        userName_editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editprof_userName);
        password_editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editprof_password);
        dob_editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editprof_dob);
        genderRadioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.editprof_radiogroup);
        editBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.editprof_editbtn);
        deleteBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.editprof_deletebtn);
        intent = getIntent();


        dbHandler = new DBHandler(EditProfile.this);

        setUserDetails();

        deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String username = userName_editText.getText().toString();

                if(username == null){
                    Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this,"Please enter username to delete your profile",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    UserProfile.Users users = dbHandler.readAllInfor(username);

                    if(users == null){
                        Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this,"No profile found from this username, please enter valid username",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        dbHandler.deleteInfo(username);
                        Intent redirectintent_home = new Intent("com.modelpaper.mad.it17121002.Home");
                        startActivity(redirectintent_home);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        editBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String userID_String = intent.getStringExtra(Home.USERID);
                if(userID_String == null){
                    Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this,"Error!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent redirectintent_home =  new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Home.class);
                    startActivity(redirectintent_home);
                }
                int userID = Integer.parseInt(userID_String);

                String username = userName_editText.getText().toString();
                String password = password_editText.getText().toString();
                String dob = dob_editText.getText().toString();
                int selectedGender = genderRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                genderRadioBtn = (RadioButton)findViewById(selectedGender);
                String gender = genderRadioBtn.getText().toString();

                UserProfile.Users users = UserProfile.getProfile().getUser();
                users.setUsername(username);
                users.setPassword(password);
                users.setDob(dob);
                users.setGender(gender);
                users.setId(userID);

                dbHandler.updateInfor(users);
                Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this,"Updated Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent redirectintent_home = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Home.class);
                startActivity(redirectintent_home);
            }
        });

        searchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               String username = userName_editText.getText().toString();
               if (username == null){
                   Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this,"Please enter a username",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
               else{
                   UserProfile.Users users_search = dbHandler.readAllInfor(username);


                   if(users_search == null){
                       Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this,"Please enter a valid username",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
                   else{
                       userName_editText.setText(users_search.getUsername());
                       password_editText.setText(users_search.getPassword());
                       dob_editText.setText(users_search.getDob());
                       int id = users_search.getId();
                       Intent redirectintent = new Intent("com.modelpaper.mad.it17121002.EditProfile");
                       redirectintent.putExtra(USERID_EDITPROFILE,Integer.toString(id));
                       startActivity(redirectintent);
                   }
               }
            }
        });


    }

    public void setUserDetails(){

        String userID_String = intent.getStringExtra(Home.USERID);
        if(userID_String == null){
            Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this,"Error!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent redirectintent_home = new Intent("com.modelpaper.mad.it17121002.Home");
            startActivity(redirectintent_home);
        }
        int userID = Integer.parseInt(userID_String);
        UserProfile.Users users = dbHandler.readAllInfor(userID);
        userName_editText.setText(users.getUsername());
        password_editText.setText(users.getPassword());
        dob_editText.setText(users.getDob());
    }
}
```